# Have no clue how to fix a bug

Tags: c, file, format, scanf, srt

I am using fscanf to scan a formatted .srt file, however I've run into a problem which I can't work around since I am fairly new to C.

I have tried reading a file char by char but it ended up being a huge mess which I couldn't debug

```
if (input == NULL) 
    {
        printf("File doesn't exist, exiting!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("File opened!\n");

    int order; //number of line

    int csh; //hh
    int csm; //mm
    int css; //ss
    int csms; //ms

    int ceh; // same order as above
    int cem;
    int ces;
    int cems;

    char* text = calloc(256, sizeof(char));
    char c;

    int count = 0;
    while ((i = fscanf(input, "%d\n%d:%d:%d,%d --> %d:%d:%d,%d\n%10s", &order, &csh, &csm, &css, &csms, &ceh, &cem, &ces, &cems, text) > 0) )
    {
        count++;
        printf("%d\n%d:%d:%d,%d --> %d:%d:%d,%d\n%s",  order,  csh, csm, css,  csms,  ceh,  cem,  ces,  cems, text);

if (count == 2) 
        {
            int xyx;
            scanf_s("%d", &xyx);
        }




    }
```

So I am trying to read a formatted file and to store data in a doubly linked list, and file look like this

[image]

Etc. File is a huge one, whole subtitles of Phantom Menace I believe, so I have two problems, my code doesn't read a whole text when it finishes with time and secondly, it doesn't get past the counter of 2 which I used just to test the program.

I get this output 
[image]

Comment: Before trying to read a huge file of subtitle, you should try to parse to example data you craft, like only two first line of text. Note that the `%10s` syntax will stop reading text as soon as it find a space in your text. You should read http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html to learn more about `scanf` functions family

Comment: Posting text as _text_ is more useful than text as  a picture.

Comment: OT: in general, it is best to honor the right margin of a printed page. (usually 72 or 80 characters)  This is easily done with the posted code by starting a newline after each comma in the parameters to the `fscanf()` function and `printf()` function

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("File doesn't exist, exiting!\n");`  This does not tell the user the cause of the error (it might not be 'File doesn't exist'   Suggest using: `perror( "fopen failed" );`  as this will output that error message AND the text reason the system thinks the operation failed.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `exit(1);`  You might want to learn about: `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` as exposed by the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score -1):

Mathieu's comment gave me a clue, I solved my problems with this:

```
while (i = fgetc(input) != EOF) 
    {
        while ((i = fscanf(input, "%d\n%d:%d:%d,%d --> %d:%d:%d,%d\n%[^'']", &order, &csh, &csm, &css, &csms, &ceh, &cem, &ces, &cems, text) > 0))
        {

            printf("%d\n%d:%d:%d,%d --> %d:%d:%d,%d\n%s\n", order, csh, csm, css, csms, ceh, cem, ces, cems, text);



        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not correct: `while ((i = fscanf(input, "%d\n%d:%d:%d,%d --> %d:%d:%d,%d\n%[^'']", &order, &csh, &csm, &css, &csms, &ceh, &cem, &ces, &cems, text) > 0))`  Suggest: `while ((i = fscanf(input, "%d\n%d:%d:%d,%d --> %d:%d:%d,%d\n%[^'']", &order, &csh, &csm, &css, &csms, &ceh, &cem, &ces, &cems, text) == 10))`   Notice the comparison to 10 (the number of input format specifiers)  Any other returned value indicates an error occurred

Comment: OT:  for safety (avoiding any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior) always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  1 less than the length because that input specifier '[...]' (and '%s') always append a NUL byte to the input

Comment: regarding: `while (i = fgetc(input) != EOF)`  This will consume a character from the input file that you do not want to lose.  Suggest: `while ((i = fscanf(input, "%d\n%d:%d:%d,%d --> %d:%d:%d,%d\n%255[^'']", &order, &csh, &csm, &css, &csms, &ceh, &cem, &ces, &cems, text) == 10))` as the loop control statement.  And since the variable 'i' is not being used, the `i =` can be deleted